# atk4 4.2.5 Schema generator issue

Tags: php, atk4

I'm learning agile toolkit by following the jobeet tutorial, but the schema generator doesn't work. It throws the following error:

```
Error in AJAX response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllHash() on a non-object in
C:\@Documentos\Personales\CODING\xampp\htdocs\zordon\atk4-addons\mvc\Page\SchemaGenerator.php
on line 77
```

By the way $this->add('jUI'); is already included in the frontend api, and the model is very simple:

```
class Model_Group extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code = 'group';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('group_id');
        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('post_count');

        $this->addField('created_dts')->type('timestamp')->system(true);
        $this->addField('updated_dts')->type('timestamp')->system(true);
        $this->addField('expires_at')->type('date')->system(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve it.
The solution is uncomment line //$this->dbConnect(); in frontend api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have working DB connection ($this->api->db) in line 77 in SchemaGenerator.
Check your DB connection: $this->dbConnect() in Frontent and database configuration in config.php.

Also please note, that using SchemaGenerators is quite evil thing to do, but if you really want to use one, then better use up-to-date one: `atk4-addons/dynamic_model/Controller_AutoCreator_MySQL`